# Android - Facebook API : post image

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I'm building an app that allows Facebook users to create new events. I noticed that I can't create an event and add an image to it in a unique Graph API call. So I make another call to post the image:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 params.putParcelable("source", bitmap); 
 Request postImageRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), eventId + "/picture", params, HttpMethod.POST, new Callback() {
           @Override
           public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.e("", response.toString());
                finish();
           }
 });
 postImageRequest.executeAsync();
```

But but I get this error response from FB servers:

> HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 324, errorType: OAuthException,
>   errorMessage: (#324) Missing or invalid image file}, isFromCache:false

Answer (score 0):

```
Request photoImageRequest= Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), bitmap, new Request.Callback(){

@Override
public void onCompleted(Response response) {
Log.e("", response.toString());
finish();

}});
```